# C# Build - Can't Figure out Source of Path Reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I attempt to build a project (using Visual Studio 2012) I see references to file paths that no longer exist when I look at the output log.  The problem is that I don't understand what the references represent and where I need to go to change them? I don't like having them as it doesn't seem clean to me so I would like to remove it possible.

For example, in the output "F:\Websites\merge-test.WIDGETPROJECT.org..." is referenced but does not exist on our system.

Here is what seems to be the relevant portion of the output...

```
1>Target "IncrementalClean: (TargetId:60)" in file 

"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "D:\WWW\Development\Cameron\WIDGETPROJECTorg\WIDGETPROJECT.Web.dll\WIDGETPROJECT.Web.dll.csproj" (target "CoreBuild" depends on it):
1>Task "FindUnderPath" (TaskId:33)
1>  Task Parameter:Path=bin\ (TaskId:33)
1>  Task Parameter:
1>      Files=
1>          F:\Websites\merge-test.WIDGETPROJECT.org\WIDGETPROJECT.Web.dll\obj\Debug\WIDGETPROJECT.Web.pdb
1>          F:\Websites\merge-test.WIDGETPROJECT.org\WIDGETPROJECT.Web.dll\bin\WIDGETPROJECT.Web.dll
1>          F:\Websites\merge-test.WIDGETPROJECT.org\WIDGETPROJECT.Web.dll\bin\WIDGETPROJECT.Web.pdb
1>          F:\Websites\merge-test.WIDGETPROJECT.org\WIDGETPROJECT.Web.dll\bin\AjaxControlToolkit.dll
1>          F:\Websites\merge-test.WIDGETPROJECT.org\WIDGETPROJECT.Web.dll\bin\Aptify.Framework.BusinessLogic.GenericEntity.Generated.Orders.dll
1>          F:\Websites\merge-test.WIDGETPROJECT.org\WIDGETPROJECT.Web.dll\bin\AptifyApplication.dll
1>          F:\Websites\merge-test.WIDGETPROJECT.org\WIDGETPROJECT.Web.dll\bin\AptifyAttributeManagement.dll
1>          F:\Websites\merge-test.WIDGETPROJECT.org\WIDGETPROJECT.Web.dll\bin\AptifyEBusinessUser.dll
1>          F:\Websites\merge-test.WIDGETPROJECT.org\WIDGETPROJECT.Web.dll\bin\AptifyExceptionManagement.dll
1>          F:\Websites\merge-test.WIDGETPROJECT.org\WIDGETPROJECT.Web.dll\bin\AptifyGenericDataServices.dll
```

... and there is more but I think this is probably enough.

Does anyone know how to resolve?  I've done some research but haven't come across anything that seems to help.

The interesting thing is that the build succeeds.

Comment: Can't you just remove them from your solution file then?

Comment: They aren't referenced in the solution file.

Comment: They must be referenced, however they might not show in GUI sometimes. Try to open the .csproj in plain text and search for the files your looking for (the ones that can't be found) and delete them.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out - the [solution](http://briannoyesblog.azurewebsites.net/2008/05/10/the-evil-suo-file-fighting-and-winning-with-visual-studio/) was to delete all the obj/bin folders.